# Dojo 1.6 Mult-File Flash Uploader for IE with form data?

Tags: html, flash, internet-explorer, upload, dojo

I'm using the Dojo 1.6 dojox.form.Uploader in IE.  This uses the dojox.form.uploader.plugins.Flash plugin to do the upload.  In Firefox, HTML5 is used and I can submit other form data along with the uploads by calling:

```
uploaderDijit.upload({paramName:"paramValue"});
```

But in IE, the Flash version's upload function does not take the formData argument.  Is there any way I can submit other data along with the file uploads using the Flash plugin?

Here is my sample code:

```
dojo.require("dojox.form.Uploader");
dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.FileList");
dojo.require("dojox.form.uploader.plugins.Flash");

function doUpload(){
     dijit.byId("uploader").upload({param: "paramValue"});
}

function onload(){
     // create uploader & file list dijits
     var uploaderDijit = new dojox.form.Uploader({
          id: "uploader",
          url: "MyApp/MyServlet",
          multiple: true
     });
     var fileListDijit = new dojox.form.uploader.FileList({uploader:uploaderDijit});

     // insert dijits into html
     var formNode = dojo.byId("multiUploadForm");
     var uploaderDiv = document.createElement("div");
     formNode.appendChild(uploaderDiv);
     uploaderDiv.appendChild(uploaderDijit.domNode);
     uploaderDiv.appendChild(fileListDijit.domNode);
}

dojo.addOnLoad(onload);
```

And:

```
<form id="multiUploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data"></form>
<button onclick="javascript:doUpload();">Upload</button>
```

I have tried adding an input node into the form:

```
<form id="multiUploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="hidden" name="param" value="paramValue"/>
</form>
```

And I've also tried appending the parameter to the url, but no dice:

```
var uploaderDijit = new dojox.form.Uploader({
     id: "uploader",
     url: "MyApp/MyServlet?param=paramValue",
     multiple: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something else is wrong.. Following is (allthough from 1.7.2 src) the function called which you state is your entrypoint in first code block. with 100% certainty, your GET parameter should be set if you use `url: "MyApp/MyServlet?param=paramValue"`
.

```
uploadFlash: function(/*Object ? */formData){
        // summary:
        //              Uploads selected files. Alias "upload()" should be used instead.
        // tags:
        //              private
        this.onBegin(this.getFileList());
        formData.returnType = "F";
        this.flashMovie.doUpload(formData);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I will give 1.7.2 a try since there is an obvious difference.  The 1.6 code doesn't handle the formData argument.